# to find motion vector from 10 previous frames

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

i want to find motion vector from previous 10 frames by dividing the frames into 8x8 subblocks and compare each block of the current frame with the neighboring blocks of the previous 10 frames.

I could do manipulation with the single frame but i feel difficult to work with N number of frames.

I need the help of others if anybody knows I need the code of this module in opencv/c++.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can try https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/2.4.10.x-prep/samples/c/motempl.c

Comment: -1 You need to post a specific question, the code you tried, the error you have. However why don't you simply use optical flow to find motion vectors?

Comment: if you want to use block matching, what prevents you from comparing 2 arbitrary images (distance 1, 2, 3 etc doesnt matter imho)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're asking about optical flow.

There are currently [two quick and easy methods for optical flow in Python](http://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_lucas_kanade.html). It's not C++, but you can start there and see if it does what you want it to.

1. Lucas-Kanade, which uses feature descriptors found from an algorithm of your choice (SIFT, SURF, ORB, BRISK, BRIEF, etc, etc). The example I linked uses Shi-Tomasi. All of these points are tracked from frame to frame.
2. Dense Optical Flow, by Farneback, which gives the motion of every single pixel in the image. The algorithm gives you more information, but it takes longer to compute.

If either of those algorithms seem to work, you can find some example code (probably just by Googling "opencv c++ optical flow example") and working from there.

Comment: For future reference, motion vectors in the context of blocks probably refers to something else than optical flow, which considers individual pixel movement. See for example section 2 in this paper: http://www.computer-vision.org/4security/pdf/saskatchewan.pdf